# Impossible delete S3: access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried different policies for the bucket and gave access to a bucket only for one specific user. That user doesn't exist anymore and I can not do anything with the bucket. When I try to do something with bucket I get: access denied.
My current user has full admin access.
Impossible change policy or delete bucket. The goal is to remove the bucket.

I tried to create another user with full access and make some actions with a bucket, no success.
The solution I know is to delete my account, but I am not sure that the bucket will be deleted too.

[image]
[image: * http://joxi.ru/DmBZqwGTJnwPdm]
[image: * http://joxi.ru/p274v0xUKqoEYA]

Comment: have you tried using aws console?

Comment: Are the images from the console with the root account or with a regular admin account?

Comment: I tried use AWS Console and AWS CLI, no success
I tried with regular user with AdminFullAccess and with root user, no success

Comment: @IaroslavDavydiak (1) What makes you think that your "current user has full admin access"? Can you show us? (2) Are you sure that when you run commands on the command-line, you are using credentials associated with that same user?

Comment: @John Rotenstein (1)here is my user permission: http://joxi.ru/VrwzNRwt7L8R1A
(2) http://joxi.ru/KAxJN3wtZO1GLm

Comment: The `rm` command will not work on a bucket, you should use `rb` (remove bucket). The `aws s3 ls s3://dave2612/` command should work. Let's try some things... Can you create another bucket and use it okay? Is it only this bucket that is giving you problems?

Comment: @John Rotenstein It doesn't work http://joxi.ru/BA0GN8ZhMkn9z2

Comment: Can you create another bucket and use it okay? Is it only this bucket that is giving you problems?

Comment: @John Rotenstein Yes, I have problem only with one bucket. as i wrote above, it is because of policy that I gave to bucket.
I gave access to bucket only for one user, but this user doesn't exist any more

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it create issues while deleting S3 bucket because of the following reasons:

- You may have objects in bucket.
- You may have versioning enabled for the bucket.

This [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/delete-bucket-s3-console-cli/) may help you.

Comment: Thanks Hassan, I so that video but in my case it doesn't work. Here are some more screenshots:      http://joxi.ru/5mdB5yEc373PoA      http://joxi.ru/52aBExMcEJEB7A       http://joxi.ru/zAN6GbLCvGvNJA

Comment: no, I don't have access to bucket. I can't do anything with bucket. but as i remember I used this guide https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/ and I used this one http://joxi.ru/v29Gov1hZMZBvr

Comment: in example we have AIDAEXAMPLEID and AROAEXAMPLEID. I specified only AIDAEXAMPLEID(my UserID,got with awc cli), but didn't specified AROAEXAMPLEID

Answer (score 0):

The situation appear to be:

- You are having difficulties with one specific bucket
- You can access/manage all other buckets
- You gave access to bucket only for one user, but this user doesn't exist any more
- You are unable to change the Bucket Policy or delete the bucket
- The goal is to delete the bucket

There are a few options...

**Use root credentials**

Root credentials have total permission over an account and bypass IAM. The login username would be an email address. Using root credentials *should* give permission to delete the bucket policy and then delete the bucket.

**Masquerade as the old user**

If the IAM User record for that user still exists, you could reset the password and login as that user, then delete the bucket policy. If the IAM User has been deleted, you could try to recreate it and then login as that user. Depending upon how the bucket policy was written, this might be sufficient to be able to delete the bucket policy. (That is, if the user is referenced by name it will work, but if referenced by canonical ID it would not work.)

**Contact AWS Support**

They might be able to walk you through some other process if the above options fail.